# Generate webservice server from WSDL file

Tags: python, web-services, soap, wsdl, zeep

first of all I know there is similar question but it has more than 11 years so it's not quite new.

I am trying to create mock webservice from WSDL (+xsd) file, but I cannot find any solution in python frameworks for it. I was trying to create Zeep client, but it dosen't support server side, only mocking requests provided in code. I was also trying to create SOAP server by spyne, but this on the other hand dosen't provide support for WSDL files. For it I was trying to find library which could translate WSDL file into compatible class but I wasn't able to find one.

Does anyone know framework/library which could help me with this? Either allowing to create webservice from wsdl as server(on localhost), or at least translate WSDL into class comptaible with Spyne.

Comment: When it comes to SOAP/WSDL support, Python is lacking unfortunately. But do you need a Python mock service or do you just need a mock service? If it's just a mock you need, then you can build one with SoapUI: https://www.soapui.org/docs/soap-mocking/service-mocking-overview/

Comment: I need to be able to run this as container in k8s and generate it on the go from wsdl :/